# Kubernetes Service Access in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes

**I am new on K8s "Need Help"**

I have created an HA Cluster of Kubernetes in AWS with Private DNS.

I used ´type: LoadBalancer´ and getting an External IP through with I am accessing my service in the browser but the problem is External Ip is PUBLIC and anyone can easily able to access which I don't want.

I used NODEPORT and Got EndPoints But can't able to access on the browser.

Now Question is.-

**How to spin up private containers services in k8s AWS which are private and I can only access?**

Answer (score 2):

If you're using AWS load balancers in services you can specify that you want internal load balancer only:

```
metadata:
    name: my-service
    annotations:
        service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: 0.0.0.0/0
```

You can read more about this here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#internal-load-balancer

Comment: as per doc, I am using annotation and I am getting an external IP with starting-`internal-ace0afab318` But on browser `This site can’t be reached`
Any Comment?

Answer (score 0):

A `ClusterIP` type Service won't be reachable from outside the cluster.

For debugging purposes, on reasonably current Kubernetes, you can set up a port forward to the Service

```
kubectl port-forward service/my-service 8888:80
```

though this isn't a good way to access it in anything that looks even a little bit like a production environment: IME it falls over somewhat routinely and needs to be restarted.

Comment: I have done the same, I have forwarded my services But I don't know which IP I will use to access the service in the browser

Comment: On the system you run `kubectl port-forward`, `http://localhost:8888` where 8888 is the first port number (it does not have to match the port number in the Service, which is the second port number).  This path really isn't reliable enough to access it from anywhere else.

Comment: `kubectl port-forward service/activemq-activemq-cluster-ui 8888:8161
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:8888 -> 8161
Forwarding from [::1]:8888 -> 8161`and when I am hitting browser with `http://localhost:8888` getting output `This site can’t be reached`